# Excel 2007 gets CSV file wrong?

Tags: excel, delphi, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7 to generate CSV file from data acquired from COM port. Now, this seems to work OK since any other spreadsheet software reads generated file properly (Open Office and Libre Office spreadshhet software, for instance). Excel 2007 does the following. Instead of  these two column values:

```
1.976139e-2<TAB>22.98027
```

i got these two column values:

```
1.98E+04<TAB>2.298.027
```

Note that generated file opened in any text editor (Notepad++ for instance) has proper values.
What could be the problem here ?

Thanks,

Josip

Comment: Lokks like the decimal separator gets mixed up with the thousand separator.

Comment: Excel has serious issues with decimal/thousands separators

Comment: Thanks. I'll check my "regional" settings in Windows. There might be some problem although that does not explain why other software is reading it OK.

Comment: Excel has its own settings. There is an issue with Excel.

Comment: @DaniloCasa:  Sorry, but what value does the `delphi-7` tag to this question, especially 3 years after it was asked?  Any interested reader would find it from the `delphi` tag anyway, and there is nothing `delphi-7` specific about the q.  Same for many of the other tag edits lately.

Answer (score 3):

If the setting in Delphi do not fit your needs you could change them before loading the CSV. But you should make sure to reset them afterwards.

```
var
  Excel, WorkBook: Variant;
  KeepDecimalSeparator, KeepThousandsSeparator: String;
  KeepUseSystem: Boolean;
begin
  Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Excel.Visible := true;
  try
    KeepDecimalSeparator := Excel.DecimalSeparator;
    KeepThousandsSeparator := Excel.ThousandsSeparator;
    KeepUseSystem := Excel.UseSystemSeparators;
    Excel.DecimalSeparator := '.';
    Excel.ThousandsSeparator := ',';
    Excel.UseSystemSeparators := false;
    WorkBook := Excel.WorkBooks.Open('C:\Temp\1.csv');
  finally
    Excel.DecimalSeparator := KeepDecimalSeparator;
    Excel.ThousandsSeparator := KeepThousandsSeparator;
    Excel.UseSystemSeparators := KeepUseSystem;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'll try it and repoert back the results. :)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use quotes.

```
"1.976139e-2"<TAB>"22.98027"
```